# Setting a default placeholder image WITHOUT link

Tags: post-thumbnails

Can anyone help?

I'm trying to show a default placeholder image on my posts when the user hasn't uploaded an image.

I have the below code BUT i need to rewrite it so that the link isn't applied to the placeholder image - only the uploaded image.

Unfortunately my PHP isn't great at all so would appreciate some help..

```
<div class="imageContainer"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
           <?php
    // Must be inside a loop.

    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail('size-2');
    }
    else {
        echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/shared/placeholder.jpg" />';
    }
    ?>
            </a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="imageContainer">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('size-2'); ?></a>
    <?php else : ?>
        <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>/images/shared/placeholder.jpg" />
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was getting in a pickle with how to write my link inside the function

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the thumbnail HTML before it is printed out. If it is empty – return the placeholder.

This should go into your theme’s `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'wpse_63591_default_thumb' );

function wpse_63591_default_thumb( $html )
{
    if ( '' !== $html )
    {
        return '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . $html . '</a>';
    }

    return '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/shared/placeholder.jpg" />';    
}
```

In your template just use

```
the_post_thumbnail('size-2');
```

No conditionals or complicated PHP needed anymore. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - forgive me if I'm being a little slow here, I'm quite new to wordpress. Where would I add the conditional 'link' part?

Comment: @VNeal I made an update to my answer to make that more clear.